# How to convert QPixMap to QPainterPath and vice-versa?

Tags: c++, qt

- I am trying to implement a pattern recognition algorithm.
- I have set up a QWidget with a QPixMap on which the user can draw the pattern with his/her mouse.
- Assuming the user draws a '3', the program should save all the points (x and y coordinates) in that drawing into an xml file so that the file can be loaded and the shape be recognized.
- I know there is a (de)serialization operator built in QDataStream for QPainterPath but how would I convert the drawing into a QPainterPath?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting errors? Without seeing some code of what you're trying and the errors you're running into, it's very hard to offer any helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for somekind of heuristics for vectorization of pixel data. There is no such thing built into Qt. I would suggest researching vectorization.

The best I can suggest is that if you are also writing the drawing tool, then trace the path as the user draws it and save it as QPicture, that way it is never on pixel form.

Comment: I found an alternative way to doing what I needed: adding the event->pos() to a vector during mouseMoveEvent() as a QPoint and then saving the data from that vector