# Construct a QPainterPath from an image

Tags: python, image-processing, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

Take this image for example:

[image]

Is it possible to construct a QPainterPath (the path being the black shape / outline) from the image?

I know you could manually define this shape with QPainterPath methods (`quadTo`, `cubicTo`, `lineTo`, etc — though it would be difficult to accurately recreate) and set a QPen with an appropriate width. But I am wondering if there is any way, by reading the pixel data or otherwise, to define a QPainterPath based on the black pixels.

My goal is to fill the inside of the shape (displayed in a GUI), and I **highly prefer** to do this with QPainter rather than flood fill an image because:

- It's 100x faster than a flood fill.
- The lines are antialiased (and as a result a flood fill leaves white/grey pixels around the outline).
- Flood filling is limited to a solid color whereas QPainter could fill with textures, patterns, and gradients.

Comment: "It's 100x faster than a flood fill" while that might be true, what makes you think that vectorizing a raster image is faster? Vectorization is actually pretty complex, it's based on heuristics and optimizations that have to be done possibly multiple times on the image. There could be a way through a mix of [`createMaskFromColor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#createMaskFromColor) or [`createHeuristicMask()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#createHeuristicMask) along with QRegion, but the question is: is it worth it? I'd just spend some time on a manually built QPainterPath.

Comment: Anyway, this question was already asked here: [How to convert QPixMap to QPainterPath and vice-versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55814431/how-to-convert-qpixmap-to-qpainterpath-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments and in the (possibly) [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55814431/how-to-convert-qpixmap-to-qpainterpath-and-vice-versa), Qt has no method for vectorization of raster images.

Besides recreating the path manually, better "flood" results *could* be achieved for simple images with large borders like those in the example.

The issue is, obviously, the antialiasing of the inner part of the image (and of the outer parts, if you want to use a different color).
The trick is to do what is generally done with raster image manipulation programs, which is to create a mask based on a color, and extend that mask "feathering" it.

In Qt terms, this can be achieved with small ellipses (2 pixels wide) centered at the middle of pixels that are part of the mask. Since there's no way to know the boundaries of the mask, we need to cycle through *all* pixels of the region and draw the smooth pixels whenever the points are within the region.

As you can see, the result is pretty good, but still far from perfect (the simple masking is the middle image, while the pseudo-antialiasing is on the right):

[image: masking and pseudo-antialiasing]

This is an example that shows the whole process, including both the simple masking and the "smooth" pixel trick:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.sourceLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.sourceLabel)
        self.maskedLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.maskedLabel)
        self.targetLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.targetLabel)

        self.border = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.red)
        self.color = QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.green)

        self.sourceLabel.installEventFilter(self)
        self.maskedLabel.installEventFilter(self)
        self.targetLabel.installEventFilter(self)

        self.processPixmap('cloud.png')

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            self.setColor(event.pos() in self.innerMask)
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def setColor(self, inside):
        dialog = QtWidgets.QColorDialog(self.color, self)
        if dialog.exec_():
            if inside:
                self.color = dialog.currentColor()
            else:
                self.border = dialog.currentColor()
            self.processPixmap()

    def processPixmap(self, path=None):
        if path is None:
            path = self.path
        self.path = path
        self.sourceLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(path))

        source = QtGui.QImage(path)
        fullMask = source.createHeuristicMask()
        fullMaskRegion = QtGui.QRegion(QtGui.QBitmap(fullMask))
        outColor = source.pixel(0, 0)
        borderMask = source.createMaskFromColor(outColor)
        borderMaskRegion = QtGui.QRegion(QtGui.QBitmap(borderMask))
        self.innerMask = fullMaskRegion - borderMaskRegion
        outerMask = fullMaskRegion + borderMaskRegion

        masked = QtGui.QPixmap(source.size())
        masked.fill(self.border)
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(masked)
        qp.setClipRegion(fullMaskRegion)
        qp.drawImage(0, 0, source)
        qp.setClipRegion(self.innerMask)
        qp.fillRect(source.rect(), self.color)
        qp.end()
        self.maskedLabel.setPixmap(masked)

        t = QtCore.QElapsedTimer()
        t.start()
        output = QtGui.QPixmap(source.size())
        output.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(output)
        qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
        qp.save()
        qp.setClipRegion(fullMaskRegion)
        qp.fillRect(source.rect(), self.border)
        qp.drawImage(0, 0, source)
        qp.restore()

        qp.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        pixel = QtCore.QRectF(-.5, -.5, 2, 2)
        for rowPixel in range(output.height()):
            for colPixel in range(output.width()):
                p = QtCore.QPoint(colPixel, rowPixel)
                if p in self.innerMask:
                    qp.setBrush(self.color)
                    qp.drawEllipse(pixel.translated(p))
                if not p in outerMask:
                    qp.setBrush(self.border)
                    qp.drawEllipse(pixel.translated(p))
        qp.end()
        self.targetLabel.setPixmap(output)

        print('Antialiasing finished in {}ms'.format(t.elapsed()))

import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Test()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can click on the outer parts of any image to select the external color, and the inner to select the background color.

Comment: Thank you, this at least capacitates filling with any QBrush and handles the antialiasing pretty well

Comment: @alec note that this is far from perfect: it works fine with "pastel" colors and contours that are not too thin, and it certainly doesn't work well with straight and well defined horizontal or vertical lines, as they will be "softened" even if their source isn't. But, yes, it's an acceptable workaround. Also consider that processing all the pixels takes some amount of time: for your source image it requires about 100ms on my 8 years old 4 core i5, which is *a lot* of time. If you're going to process larger images, you should consider looking into image dedicated libraries, like OpenCV.